# How can I get revenge on someone if they are in my clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If someone attacked me and then joined my clan would I still be able to use the revenge button? It seems to not be available now since he has joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF someone attacks you, and then joins your clan, you would be unable to use the 'revenge' option on them. If they join and then leave, you can once again attack them.

Have fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

I joined the guy who attacked me then looked at his traps and stuff and revenged him(I even asked him for troops to to it) so it's possible unless something happened in the update I dunno

Comment: I will give it a try sometime. This is fun!

Answer (score -1):

No it isn't possible without hacking or exploting the game.